# How can I optimise my game and its game objects?

Tags: unity, c#, blender

I have a 3D game in Unity and I use blender to design models for it. My game has a feature where if you click a button, an object is cloned. An example from my game is a tree that is cloned around 100 times with different sizes and positions to form a forest.

The issue is that after a few presses of the button, the game starts to really lag. Is there a way to optimise the game in Unity or optimise the models in Blender to reduce this lag? I use the instantiate function in Unity to do my cloning.

Some useful information for a generic gameobject (all of them are similar in complexity):

- faces: 12,226
- triangles: 26,116
- memory: 13.24 mb
- gameobjects in scene not static
- CPU usage mostly spent on rendering

Here is a screenshot showing my game running, where the blue part on the graph in the middle is when I click the button:
[image]

Here is a detailed look into the spikes you can see:
[image]

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the nature of your scene? What kind of polygon count do these trees have? What kinds of materials do they use? Are they marked static? Do they have collision? What other components are there on them? What does your profiler tell you about where the most frame time is being spent?

Comment: Your profiler screenshot shows you're mostly running at 60 FPS apart from occasional spikes. Can you drill into one of those spikes to identify what's different about those frames? Often, spikes like this in Unity are caused by editor updates/repaints, so they might not represent a performance problem in a built game executable.

Comment: @DMGregory a spike occurs in the “gc allocated” (red) section every time, just before one of those green spikes. I have edited my question to show this

Comment: Why does your tree model have 26000 triangles? It certainly will cause lag after a couple of presses. Most games only dedicate half that much polygons to the main character and you know, there's only ever one of that.

Comment: @Bálint is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: @FinnWilliams reduce the vertices on your tree and re-export?

Comment: Don't just hit subdivide when you need extra detail. Trees in most modern games are just a couple dozen planes, because they look believable enougj